# Rails email name label

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, mandrill

I'm using Rails + Mandrill (via SMTP) to send emails.
The emails are sent from `foo@example.com` but I want users to see a nice name like `John Doe` instead of the email address when receiving the mail. Can this be achieved through rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Mailer class put something like

```
default from: 'John Doe <foo@example.com>'
```

For example

```
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'John Doe <foo@example.com>'

  def example_mail
    ...
  end
end
```